# TFS 2012 Backups w/DPM

Tags: windows-server-2012, team-foundation-server, sql-server-2012, scdpm

I have a few servers running (mixture of 2012 and 2012 R2) and am playing with Microsoft's DPM as a backup solution. One of the things it complained about during installation was ensuring the SQL Server service I am configuring it to connect to needs to run under LocalSystem. I did that and everything is fine, but now when I try to do any type of backup of TFS through TFS Admin, it errors out because LocalSystem can't connect to any of our shares on any devices because it's not a domain account.

Suggestions? I already backup the SQL Server instance where TFS is, but I'd like to use their built-in utility as well as a further measure.

This is with SQL 2012 and TFS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Run it as Network Service. If you need more permission, run it as a domain account with whatever permissions are required

Comment: Would the main permission needed be run as a local service if I switch to domain account?

Comment: What happens if you use Network Service is on a dozen? You should be able to use it without issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "is on a dozen"?

Comment: Run SQL Server as Network Service. Network Service allows it to authenticate on a different machine. Local System is for local use only. I don't know what happened to the message above. It must have been spell corrected somehow, but I can't remember what I was trying to say.